# Sum of extensions in matrix form

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is exercise IX.1 from "C* Algebras by Example" by Davidson.

Suppose that $(\mathcal{E}_{i},\varphi_{i})$ represent two extensions of $\mathcal{K}$ (compact operators) by $C(X)$. Show that the sum of extensions is given by

$$
\{\begin{bmatrix}
E_{11} & K_{12}\\
K_{21} & E_{22}
\end{bmatrix} : E_{ii} \in \mathcal{E}_{i}, K_{ij} \in \mathcal{K}, \varphi_{1}(E_{11})=\varphi_{2}(E_{22})\}$$
Could anyone give me a hint on how to approach this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition is defined for monomorphisms, $[\tau_1]+[\tau_2]=[\tau_1\oplus\tau_2]$. The exercise seems to ignore the identification between $M_2(B(H))$ and $B(H)$, and just wants the result on $M_2(B(H))$. $\def\E{\mathcal E}$

We will have $\E_1+\E_2=\pi_2^{-1}((\tau_1\oplus \tau_2)(C(X))$. In this context $\pi_2:M_2(B(H))\to M_2(B(H)/K(H))$ is the quotient map, which can be seen as the $2\times 2$ amplification of the usual quotient map. So we are looking at
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \tau_1(f)&0\\0&\tau_2(f)\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \pi(T_{11})& \pi(T_{12})\\ \pi(T_{21})&\pi(T_{22})\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This forces $\pi(T_{12})=\pi(T_{21})=0$, so $T_{12},T_{21}\in K(H)$, and
$$
\varphi_1(T_{11})=\tau_1^{-1}\pi(T_{11})=f=\tau_2^{-1}\pi(f)=\varphi_2(T_{22}). 
$$

Comment: Thank you! Two questions: What would be the results on $B(H)$ that you are alluding to? And $T_{11},T_{12},T_{21},T_{22}$ is some decomposition of an operattor T embedded into a 2x2 matrix right?

Comment: Also what property of $/pi$ does it allow to look at the value of the matrix elementwise?

Comment: It's not "embedded" ; you should check that there is a natural identification between $B(H\oplus H)$ and $M_2(B(H))$. In that context, you can also identify $K(H\oplus H)$ with $M_2(K(H))$, and the quotient map onto the Calkin can be identified with $$\begin{bmatrix} T_{11}&T_{12}\\ T_{21}&T_{22}\end{bmatrix}\longmapsto \begin{bmatrix} \pi(T_{11})&\pi(T_{12})\\ \pi(T_{21})&\pi(T_{22})\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: By natural identification you mean showing that there is an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, but the isomorphism is natural, it's not just some isomorphism.

Comment: Is there some reference for this or is this trivial to proof?

Comment: It's kind of trivial. If you know how to show that $B(\mathbb C^2)$ can be canonically seen as $M_2(\mathbb C)$ (which you should), it's basically the same argument. There is usually some discussion of this in textbooks, but it is mostly confined to exercises.